# Validations on key press event with the help of Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am unable to contruct validations for following conditions in regex :

> - Allow only **letters with spaces** in textbox on keypress event
> - Allow only **numbers without spaces** in textbox on keypress event
> - Allow only **numbers with only upto 2 decimals values are allowed** in textbox on keypress event

I have tried the following code to disallow numbers:

```
if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) != 8)
{
    errorprovider.SetError(product_combobox, "Only letters allowed");
    e.Handled = true;

    product_combobox.Focus();
}
else
{
    errorprovider.Clear();
}
```

Comment: @SonerGönül yes check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some regular expressions which match your criteria if checked against the entire value of the textbox. It's not enough to check on keypress, since there may be other ways a user can get values into the field - by pasting a bunch of text, for example.

- Allow only letters with spaces in textbox on keypress event

`^[a-zA-Z ]*$`

- Allow only numbers without spaces in textbox on keypress event

`^[0-9]*$`

- Allow only numbers with only upto 2 decimals values are allowed in textbox on keypress event

`^[0-9]*([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,2})*$`